# Install packages for kinect

Tags: ros-kinetic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does everyone know, how to use the description package for the Innok Heros in kinetic, not Indigo?

http://wiki.ros.org/innok_heros_gazebo/Tutorials/Simulating%20Innok%20Heros

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288531/install-packages-for-kinect/) by [ich4913](https://answers.ros.org/users/34627/ich4913/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For packages that have no binary release for a particular ROS version (or OS), you can always try to build them from sources.

No guarantees though (dependencies could not be available, there could be breaking changes in dependencies, etc).

See #q252478 for the general procedure. Pay special attention to where the dependencies are installed.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1